# Get totals of an array in a loop

Tags: php

Trying to find total vacancy days in investment properties...

I'm getting info from mysql putting it into a looped array to find the difference between dates in different rows.

I am able to return the difference between each "move out" and "move in" dates, but am unable to get a running total.
The code below returns this...

Difference between 2014-01-25 and 2014-01-27 on Property# 7 = 2

Difference between 2014-11-03 and 2014-11-23 on Property# 7 = 20

```
  mysql_select_db($database_rent, $rent);
    $query_RS_Vac = "SELECT Properties.PropId, Tenants.TenantId, Tenants.PropertyID,      Tenants.TenantAdress, Tenants.MoveIn, Tenants.MoveOut, Properties.P_GpNo FROM Properties,   Tenants WHERE Tenants.PropertyID=Properties.PropId  AND Tenants.TenantAdress = "7"
    ORDER BY Tenants.TenantId ";
    $result = mysql_query($query_RS_Vac) or die ("no query");
    $result_array = array();      
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $values = array($row['MoveIn'],$row['MoveOut'], $row['TenantAdress']);
    array_push($result_array,$values);
    }
    $it = 0;
    $PropId=$values[2];
    while($it<count($result_array)){
    // if neither begin and end are NULL 
    if($result_array[$it][1]!= null & $result_array[$it+1][0]!=null){
        $datetime1 = new DateTime($result_array[$it][1]);
        $datetime2 = new DateTime($result_array[$it+1][0]);
        $diff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        $days2= $diff->format("%a"); 
      echo "Difference between ".$datetime1->format("Y-m-d")." and ".$datetime2->format("Y- m-d")." on Property# " . $PropId . " = " . $days2 . "<br/>";
   } 
     $it++;       
     }
```

Comment: If you just want to add up the days put them into an array and then use array_sum when done.

Comment: You don't have a running total at all. you probably want `$total += $days2` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways

```
$total_days[]=$days2;
array_sum($total_days);
```

or

```
$total_days+=$days2;
```

Comment: Thanks Funk Doc $total_days+=$days2; did the trick. array_sum(); just repeated what I already had